# JAVA: Swing - actionPerformed() on JMenuItem fires but updated values do not Persist

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, actionlistener, jmenubar

Ok, so I have been building a simple Java Swing based GUI for an opengl graphics engine I've been developing.

The problem I'm having is that the menu bar is not functioning as I would like. Specifically, I have a MenuBarBuilder class that builds the various menus, sub-menus and menu-items. When a menu-item is added, it is assigned a new actionEventListener and given a simple task of setting a Boolean value to true; this Boolean value is stored in a list of states associated with that menu. Each menu Item state is created when adding a menu Item to a menu. The states are stored in the 'StatesList' class as an object of type 'State'.

In the MenuBarBuilder class each of the menu-items that need to function as a unit are added as a 'group'. When this is done a second action event listener is added to each menu-item that sets all the associated values of the menu group to false. Ultimately this has the effect of making sure only one menu-item in the group has a state in the states list that is set to true.

When a menu item is clicked the action listener events are fired. When fired they print out a list to determine the order they are fired in and to make sure the state values are set as expected, see below:

```
setfalse
list
MenuItem1Name: false
MenuItem2Name: false

MenuItem1Name
setTrue
list
MenuItem1Name: true
MenuItem2Name: false

setfalse
list
MenuItem1Name: false
MenuItem2Name: false

MenuItem2Name
setTrue
list
MenuItem1Name: false
MenuItem2Name: true
```

This ensures that the events are firing and in the correct order. We can see that when the *MenuItem1Name* Button is Pressed, the values are correctly set to false and the relevant field is subsequently updated to true. The same can be seen for *MenuItem2Name*. Now to get to the actual Problem.

When I get the state list and check the values in a loop via the GUI class, I only ever get 'false' values from the state list. I have implemented this pattern in a similar fashion using Swing toolbars which works fine but I simply cannot fathom why I am unable to retrieve the values that are set correctly by the action listener events. I can see no place where the values are overwritten or where there is a strange order/mixing of object instantiation.

So, the Question is:
*why do I only ever get **false** when testing the state list?*

UPDATED: attempt at SSCCE

---

[Here is UML class Diagram with the relevant classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LV9m.png)

Below is the implementation of the relevant classes.

**State.java**

```
public class State {

    private String name;
    private Object value;

    State(String name, Object value){
        this.name=name;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString(){   
        return getName() + ": " + getValue();   
    }

}
```

**StatesList.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StatesList {

    private ArrayList<State> states;

    StatesList(){
        states= new ArrayList<State>();
    }

    void addState(String name, Object value){
        states.add(new State(name, value));
    }

    State getState(String name){
        for(State s : states){
            if(s.getName().equals(name)){
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String rString="";
        rString+="list\n";
        for (State s : states) {
            rString+=s.toString()+"\n";
        }
        return rString;
    }

}
```

**MenuBar.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MenuBar {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private StatesList menustates;

    public MenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menustates = new StatesList();
    }

    void createMenu(String title) {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu(title);
        menuBar.add(menu);
    }

    void createMenuItem(JMenu menu, String itemTitle) {

        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(itemTitle);

        menustates.addState(itemTitle, false);

        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int menuItemindex = menustates.getStates().size()-1 ;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
                menustates.getStates().get(menuItemindex).setValue(true);
                //print list of current states
                System.out.println("setTrue");
                System.out.println(menustates.toString());
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);
    }

    //not a real group, just ensures MenuItem behaves the same as other menu items
    void addMenuGroup(JMenuItem[] jMenuItems, int startComponentIndex) {    

        for (int i = 0; i < jMenuItems.length; i++) {
            jMenuItems[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jMenuItems.length; i2++) {
                        //make sure each state related to the menuItemGroup is to false
                        menustates.getStates().get(i2 + startComponentIndex).setValue(false);
                    }
                    //print list of current states
                    System.out.println("setfalse");
                    System.out.println(menustates.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    public StatesList getStates() {
        return menustates;
    }


}
```

**MenuBarBuilder.java**

```
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MenuBarBuilder {

    private MenuBar DataViewMenuBar;

    MenuBarBuilder() {
        DataViewMenuBar = buildDataViewMenu();
    }

    MenuBar buildDataViewMenu() {
        MenuBar tb = new MenuBar();

        //create menu
        tb.createMenu("TestScenes");

        //add two menuItems
        tb.createMenuItem(tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0), "MenuItem1Name");
        tb.createMenuItem(tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0), "MenuItem2Name");

        //add buttons two a 'group' sort of
        tb.addMenuGroup(new JMenuItem[] { 
                (JMenuItem) tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0).getItem(0),
                (JMenuItem) tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0).getItem(1), },
                tb.getStates().getStates().size() - 2);

        return tb;
    }

    StatesList getDataViewMenuBarStates() {
        return DataViewMenuBar.getStates();
    }

    JMenuBar getDataViewMenuBarMenubar() {
        return DataViewMenuBar.getMenuBar();
    }

}
```

**GUI.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI {

    MenuBarBuilder mbb;
    boolean Selected = false;

    GUI() {
        mbb = new MenuBarBuilder();
    }

    void run() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setJMenuBar(mbb.buildDataViewMenu().getMenuBar());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (!Selected) {
            selectLoadScene();
        }
        System.out.print("bap- selection must have occured");
    }

    void selectLoadScene() {
        String selectedTest = "";


    // The Test Occurs here
    // loop through states list
        System.out.println(mbb.getDataViewMenuBarStates().getStates().toString());
        for (State s : mbb.getDataViewMenuBarStates().getStates()) {
            // check the value for each state -this value is always false,..
            // thats the problem
            if ((boolean) s.getValue() == true) {
                // if true save value
                selectedTest = s.getName();
                break;
            }
        }

        // test selected value and see if it matches the following cases
        switch (selectedTest) {
        case "MenuItem1Name":
            // dosomething
            Selected = true; // breaks while loop
            break;
        case "MenuItem2Name":
            // dosomething
            Selected = true;// breaks while loop
            break;
        default:
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

**Start.java**

```
public class Start {

    GUI gui;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui= new GUI(); 
        gui.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for javax.swing.ButtonGroup?

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I tried button group, but it doesn't play nice with JMenuItems at least it didn't when i last checked. Debugger,.. yes should have thought of that will have a go now. Apologies for the long post,.. it was my first so i wasnt really sure how to approach it

Comment: Maybe you have it backwards.  When you change the state of the model, the menu items should then update their state accordingly, so the menu items should be observing changes of the model

Comment: a kind of Model View Controller? I'm not sure what you mean exactly, ultimately the event chain will have to come from the button being pressed and thus pass some message back to the system for consumption. Perhaps i am mistaken?

Comment: Yes, he's referring to a MVC system. The event chain should go from button to control to model. The change in the model's state should then trigger a change in the view. As for the actual cause of your problem, I'm afraid that without a decent [mcve] / [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), I'm at a loss.

Comment: I ran the debugger and it just shows that the values are never set. I'll attempt a SSCCE without the fluff that compiles independently.

Comment: My bet is that there's a reference issue somewhere, but I await the SSCCE to confirm this.

Comment: Right I've removed anything that isn't relevant,.. i'm not sure how much simpler i can make it without breaking the class structure. It should compile without errors.

Comment: Running your code, I'm seeing what *looks* to be correct behavior -- one of the states is true, the one chosen in the menu.

Comment: Yeah that's whats so baffling,.. the action events fire and execute the print statements, which means they should have set the values of the state list but when the list is accessed within the selectLoadScene() method of the GUI class it's as if the values were never set. Could it have something to do with the while loop in run() blocking the action listener events? Notice that the print statement at the end of the run() method never executes.

Comment: That while loop makes no sense from an  event-driven GUI context. Why do you have that in there? And how are you testing this portion of the code in your SSCCE?

Comment: Also the state values are stored as Object type(see State class), so type safety is lost. Currently i'm only using Boolean for state values and as such i just cast to a Boolean before the check. I know this isn't robust. It is only a temporary measure and i intend to do proper type checking later, but as mentioned in the Question i have implemented this same pattern/structure using JToolBars and it works perfectly. The only difference is the while loop.

Comment: Hmm i think your right, the while loop is probably the culprit. I did it because i wasn't sure how to ensure the messages get consumed by the system when a button is pressed.

Comment: Previously i was testing it using a print statement to verify the state values being checked in selectLoadScene().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menubar in while loop is different from the menubar in the action performed methods. why?
If you carefully look at the following 2 lines from class GUI, you will come to know.

```
mbb = new MenuBarBuilder();
frame.setJMenuBar(mbb.buildDataViewMenu().getMenuBar());
```

Here 2 different menubars are created. as constructor of MenuBarBuilder internally calls buildDataViewMenu(), so 2 calls to "buildDataViewMenu()".
which will end up creating 2 menubars.

To avoid this

Dont call "buildDataViewMenu()" in

```
frame.setJMenuBar(mbb.buildDataViewMenu().getMenuBar());
```

As you just want the menubar, you should manage the code in such a way that you will get the handle for the this.tb = new MenuBar() may be you can add the getter and setter for the same.

When I added the getter and setter for the same as bellow it started working.

```
public class MenuBarBuilder {

private MenuBar DataViewMenuBar;
MenuBar tb;

MenuBarBuilder() {
    DataViewMenuBar = buildDataViewMenu();
}

MenuBar buildDataViewMenu() {
   this.tb = new MenuBar();

    //create menu
    tb.createMenu("TestScenes");

    //add two menuItems
    tb.createMenuItem(tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0), "MenuItem1Name");
    tb.createMenuItem(tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0), "MenuItem2Name");

    //add buttons two a 'group' sort of
    tb.addMenuGroup(new JMenuItem[] { 
            (JMenuItem) tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0).getItem(0),
            (JMenuItem) tb.getMenuBar().getMenu(0).getItem(1), },
            tb.getStates().getStates().size() - 2);

    return tb;
}

public MenuBar getMenuBar(){
    return this.tb;
}

StatesList getDataViewMenuBarStates() {
    return DataViewMenuBar.getStates();
}

JMenuBar getDataViewMenuBarMenubar() {
    return DataViewMenuBar.getMenuBar();
}

}
```

and in class GUI call should be like,

```
frame.setJMenuBar(mbb.getMenuBar().getMenuBar());
```

This will resolve the issue. Let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: I've made the build methods private, that should prevent me making such a silly mistake in the future,.. thank you.